# Select unique elements

Tags: c#, list

I have the following Class:

```
public class Test
{
     public string ColumnA { get; set; }
     public int ColumnB { get; set; }
     public int ColumnC { get; set; }
}
```

An the following list:

```
List<Test> testList = new List<Test>()
{
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 1", ColumnB = 1, ColumnC = 3 },
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 2", ColumnB = 2, ColumnC = 2 },
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 3", ColumnB = 1, ColumnC = 3 },
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 4", ColumnB = 4, ColumnC = 4 },
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 5", ColumnB = 5, ColumnC = 5 },
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 6", ColumnB = 7, ColumnC = 0 },
    new Test() { ColumnA = "Element 7", ColumnB = 7, ColumnC = 0 }
};
```

So, I want to select only the unique elements (that the column B and C don't is the same comparing with other elements), that is: "Element 2", "Element 4" and "Element 5".

Obs: I don't want to bring distinct elements, the elements that are repeated I don't want to bring it, both of them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results = source.GroupBy(x => new { x.ElementB, x.ElementC })
                    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                    .Select(g => g.Single());
```

Just group using `ElementB` and `ElementC` properties and take elements from groups that have only one element within it (what means they are unique).

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq to select elements that don't have a duplicate:

```
Test[] noDupes = testList.Where(item => 
    !testList.Except(new[] { item }).Any(inner => inner.Equals(item))
).ToArray();
```

(This assumes you've implemented `Equals` on `Test`, of course.)

Comment: When we use distinct, brings only one of repeated elements, right? For exemple, the list: 1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6, if I use distinct I will have another list with 1,2,3,4,5,6, ritght?

Comment: But, in my case, my goal is to bring only 2, 3, 4 and 6, because 1 and 5 are repeated. Understand?

Comment: Your edit is pointless. It won't return anything, because you'll always find at least one element within you `Any` call - the same you're actually comparing it with within `Where` iteration.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yeah, right.  I just added an `Except` the current item in there, which should fix that.

Comment: Still not better, as `Except` needs `IEnumerable` and you're trying to use it with just one element.

Answer (score 0):

What about lambda

```
    List<Test> answer = testList.Where(t => t.ColumnB == t.ColumnC).ToList();
```

Comment: The goal of question is not bring the elements that has Column B and C equal, the goal is "select only the unique elements (that the column B and C don't is the same COMPARING WITH OTHER elements)", not with itself.

Comment: I'm confused as to what "(that the column B and C don't is the same COMPARING WITH OTHER elements)" means exactly

Answer (score -1):

One could write

```
    List<Test> data = testList.FindAll(test => test.ColumnB == test.ColumnC);
```

The method `FindAll` is optimized due member of `List<T>.FindAll`